# Flutter: Make a controller available always

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a `GetXController` called `ConnectionManagerController`. This class actually checks for the internet connection.

I have controller binding

```
class ControllerBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut<ConnectionManagerController>(
        () => ConnectionManagerController());
  }
}
```

I have bind it in `main.dart` as initial binding like this.

```
runApp(GetMaterialApp(
      initialBinding: ControllerBinding(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue, fontFamily: 'Reckless'),
      home: _defaultScreen,
    ));
```

And in my all pages' Controllers I have called it like this

```
final ConnectionManagerController netcontroller = Get.find<ConnectionManagerController>();
```

And i m using `netcontroller` in respective views to show different widgets based on internet availability.

**Problem**

Now when I go to `Page 1` to `Page 2`, and come back to `Page 1`, `ConnectionManagerController` gets deleted. So its obvious when I go from `Page 1` to `Page 3`, I get error `ConnectionManagerController not found`

What I want to do is to make `ConnectionManagerController` always available. can anybody tell me where I went wrong? Any help will be highly appreicated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `GetxService` instead of `GetxController`.

https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx#getxservice

Plus, you can define a custom function as follow :

```
ConnectionManagerController getConnectionManager() {
  ConnectionManagerController _connManager;
  try {
    _connManager = Get.find();
  } catch (e) {
    Get.put(ConnectionManagerController());
    _connManager = Get.find();
  }
  return _connManager;
}
```

So that you can call `ConnectionManagerController netcontroller = getConnectionManager()` anywhere and still get your controller (and reinstantiate it if any error happened or application was closed or anything)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Adding `fenix: true`  in Bindings, prevented from deleting controller from memory. But which is optimal? This one, or `GetXService` or The custom function you have in your answer?

Comment: I personally use GetXService + my cutsom function. But custom function should be enough on it's own.